# How do I display an mySQL table live on a website without buttons?

Tags: mysql, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a node .js script that collects numbers from the web and stores them in a mySQL table.
My dream would be to have a website up and running that displays the table in near real time.
I read a bit into websockets, socket.io and reverse AJAX, but tbh I am lost.

Any advice would be very welcomed!

Comment: If it is near real time you need, then mysql is not particularly a great option for you, since it does not have the capability of notifying clients that something has changed in a dataset. Your only option is to regularly poll the database, which does not really scale. You need some kind of a message broker / queue or event bridge to do this, like redis, firebase or rabbitmq. There are tons of tutorials out there how to use these with node.js and websockets.

Comment: I have tried redis, and manged to create keys where each key stored a single value, but couldnt find a way to have the values displayed on a website

Comment: would be really awesome to got more help, I am very lost on this one..

Comment: Sorry, but not sure what help you need! There are tons of tutorials out there describing how to use websockets with node.js and the various storage dolutions. We are not going to create one more. You need to ask a specific question that we can help you with.

Comment: I went throw all the first two pages of google and all of stack overflow and no where it was mentioned how to get Redis to output the key values. Like the publish command does not publish the values. I've tried it all

Comment: Then delete this question and ask that concrete question instead by showing your code and config and describe the issue in greater detsil.